# Curl returns empty when response is too big

Tags: php, curl, post

I am sending curl request like

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.example.com/Search');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{  \"apikey\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"min\": 20,  \"items_per_page\": 5000 }");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now, when "items_per_page" parameter is set to under 4000 it works well everytime, but when its default 5000 it returns empty response.

I tryed to find the error, but its doesn't return anything

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

curl_getinfo returns http_code 504.

I also tryed adding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10000 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

etc. but still can't make it work.

Comment: 504 Gateway Timeout most likely means the server you are making the request _to_ has given up after a while, because the query took too much time to execute. This is nothing you can fix from your end.

Comment: curl 504 Gateway timeout. you have to increase the timeout from 10000 to 50000 for example and try it

Comment: You need to increase your server timeout variable in the server configuration file.